# Handle both parent and child on delegate (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, events, delegates, click

```
<ul id ='foo'>
    <li><p>hello</p></li>
    <li><p>hello</p></li>
    <li><p>hello</p></li>
</ul>

$('#foo').delegate('li', 'click', function(event) {
    if (#foo) { 
      do 
    } else if (li) {
      do 
    }
});
```

I've many objects, nearly 1000 per page. I would like to reduce number of event bindings by handling each parent and child objects on one event delegation.

How can I do this? Code above works only for li now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to execute different code depending on which element is clicked? Which elements would you like to select, `<li>` and `<p>`?

Comment: yes, #foo and li. Through one event binding.

Comment: Just add the handler to #foo, and check event.target to see which element was actually clicked. the event will bubble up from the deepest DOM element beneath the cursor

Comment: can you please provide a demo?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delegate('ul', 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.target.nodeName == 'P') { 
      alert('p clicked'); 
    } else {
      alert('parent clicked'); 
    }
});
```

This will reduce delegations to the `UL` level. Substitute `#foo` for `ul` if you like.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/zpFDa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(event) {
    var action_target = $(event.target);
    if (action_target.closest('li').length > 0) { /* an LI was clicked */ }
    else { /* Something else inside #foo was clicked */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Derek's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17730258/1636522) is nice but not fully reliable since `.closest('li')` is likely to find a list item in which `#foo` might be contained. Besides, in this case `.length > 0` will always be `true`.

That being said, there is no need to traverse up the DOM tree using `.closest()`. Indeed, we already know that the handler will be called only if `#foo` or one of its descendants is clicked, so, we just need to check whether the clicked element (`event.target`) is `#foo` (`this`) :

```
$('#foo').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        // #foo was clicked directly
    } else {
        // something inside of #foo was clicked
    }
});
```

However, `.closest()` could be useful to retrieve a particular element inside of `#foo`. Let's say we want the direct LI that was clicked in order to add a `selected` class to it :

```
$('#foo').click(function (e) {
    var item;
    if (e.target === this) {
        // #foo was clicked directly
    } else {
        // something inside of #foo was clicked
        // 3 options to find the related item :
```

```js
        // option 1 - easy to read
        item = $(e.target).closest('#foo > li');
```

```js
        // option 2 - useful if the container has no ID
        item = $(e.target).closest($(this).children());
```

```js
        // option 3 - probably the fastest one
        item = e.target;
        while (item.parentNode !== this) item = item.parentNode;
        item = $(item);
```

```js
        item.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/dE6Pj/.

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/closest/.